# Fix Query Select in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables.
First table consist datas from second and third tables.

table_0

```
id | id_table_1 |id_table_2 | people_id
1        1           0        1
2        0           2        1
3        0           0        1
4        0           1        2
```

table_1

```
  id | machine
   1    bmw
   2    reno
     ....
```

table_2

```
  id | machine
   1   yamaha
   2   ducati
   ....
```

I want to make select query which can get this result

```
tabel_0.id | table_0.people_id  | machine(table_1 or table_2) 
    1                1                      bmw
    2                1                      ducati
    3                1                       ""
```

My querys can to get only from one of tables(1 or 2)

```
select table_0.id, table_0.people_id,table_1.machine from table_0 join table_1
on table_0.id_table_1 = table_1.id and table_0.people_id = 1
```

But I need to get name machines from all tables (table_1 and table_2).
Please help to fix my query. Thanks!

Comment: Use NULL, not 0, for absent values - although problems of this nature can be symptomatic of poor design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your query forgot the second table to join on.

```
SELECT table_0.id, table_0.people_id, table_1.machine, table_2.machine 
FROM table_0 
   JOIN table_1 ON table_0.id_table_1 = table_1.id 
   JOIN table_2 ON table_0.id_table_2 = table_2.id
WHERE table_0.people_id = 1
```

You can concat the two machine columns to make them one, which would give you this

```
SELECT 
    table_0.id, table_0.people_id, 
    CONCAT(table_1.machine, ',' , table_2.machine) AS machines
FROM table_0 
   JOIN table_1 ON table_0.id_table_1 = table_1.id 
   JOIN table_2 ON table_0.id_table_2 = table_2.id
WHERE table_0.people_id = 1
```

Like Dmitry stated in the comments if you want the query to grab machines from either table_1 **or** table 2 you would use a left join, making the query...

```
SELECT 
    table_0.id, table_0.people_id, 
    CONCAT(table_1.machine, ',' , table_2.machine) AS machines
FROM table_0 
   LEFT JOIN table_1 ON table_0.id_table_1 = table_1.id 
   LEFT JOIN table_2 ON table_0.id_table_2 = table_2.id
WHERE table_0.people_id = 1
```

Comment: I am aware. I was going off of his join he had in his original query. I updated the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
  table_0.id, 
  table_0.people_id,
  table_1.machine AS machine1, 
  table_2.machine AS machine2
from table_0 
LEFT join 
  table_1 on table_0.id_table_1 = table_1.id 
LEFT join 
  table_2 on table_0.id_table_2 = table_2.id 
WHERE table_0.people_id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

So many options are available

**SELECT UNION**

```
(SELECT table_0.id, table_0.people_id, table_1.machine
FROM table_0 
JOIN table_1 ON table_0.id_table_1 = table_1.id 
WHERE table_0.people_id = 1)
UNION
(SELECT table_0.id, table_0.people_id, table_2.machine
FROM table_0 
JOIN table_2 ON table_0.id_table_2 = table_2.id 
WHERE table_0.people_id = 1)
```

**IFNULL**

```
SELECT table_0.id, table_0.people_id, 
       IFNULL(table_1.machine, table_2.machine) AS machine
FROM table_0 
LEFT JOIN table_1 ON table_0.id_table_1 = table_1.id 
LEFT JOIN table_2 ON table_0.id_table_2 = table_2.id
WHERE table_0.people_id = 1
```

Hope it helps